# Dynamic path segment OR 404

Tags: react-router

I have an app that needs to check with a backend API before rendering 404. The routing flow works something like this:

Request comes in to /{INCOMING_PATH}, and the application attempts to fetch and render data from api.com/pages/{INCOMING_PATH}.

If the API returns 404, then the app should return 404. If not, the data is rendered.

I'm not sold on using  for this use case. {INCOMING_PATH} will be dynamic, potentially with slashes and extensions in the path. Is this possible to implement in React Router (with proper SSR behavior too)? If so, how should I proceed?

([This question was originally posted on github](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/2827) by another user. They were requested to post it here as it is a support request. But it doesn't seem they did. I am now stuck on exactly the same issue.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this with the [React Nested Status](https://github.com/Ambroos/react-nested-status) module.

I'm using https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example so this code is geared towards that. See [React Nested Status](https://github.com/Ambroos/react-nested-status) for a more generic solution.

Edits to server.js:

at the top

```
import NestedStatus from 'react-nested-status';
```

at the bottom replace:

```
const status = getStatusFromRoutes(routerState.routes);
if (status) {
  res.status(status);
}
res.send('<!doctype html>\n' +
  ReactDOM.renderToString(<Html assets={webpackIsomorphicTools.assets()} component={component} store={store}/>));
```

with:

```
const repsonse = ReactDOM.renderToString(
  <Html assets={webpackIsomorphicTools.assets()} component={component} store={store}/>
);

const status = getStatusFromRoutes(routerState.routes);
if (status) {
  res.status(status);
}

const nestedStatus = NestedStatus.rewind();
if (nestedStatus !== 200) {
  res.status(nestedStatus);
}

res.send('<!doctype html>\n' + repsonse);
```

Then in what ever container/component you need to serve a 404 :

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import connectData from 'helpers/connectData';
import { fetchApiData } from 'redux/modules/foo/fetchApiData';
import { NotFound } from 'containers';

@connectData(null, (getReduxState, dispatch, state, params) => {
  return dispatch(fetchApiData(params.fooId));
})
@connect(
  (reduxState) => ({
    fooData: reduxState.foo.data,
  })
)
export default class ProductType extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    fooData: PropTypes.object,
  }

  render() {
    let content;
    // ... whatever your api sends back to indicate this is a 404
    if (!this.props.fooData.exists) {
      content = <NotFound/>;
    } else {
      content = (
        <div className={styles.productType}>
          Normal content...
        </div>
      );
    }
    return content;
  }
}
```

Finally replace /src/containers/NotFound/NotFound.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import NestedStatus from 'react-nested-status';

export default class NotFound extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <NestedStatus code={404}>
        <div className="container">
          <h1>Error 404! Page not found.</h1>
        </div>
      </NestedStatus>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what kind of state implementation you are using. But, if you are using redux, then I think the simplest way is to use [redux-simple-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router-redux). With it, your Routes are synchronized within your state, so you can dispatch action creators to change the router path. I would try to update satate with action creators  instead of pushing the state directly from a component. The truth point must be always the state, in your case I would act as follows:

The component that requires to fetch the data will be subscribed to the "dataReducer" which is the isolated state part that this component should care about. Maybe the initial state of `dataReducer` is an empty array. Then, in `componentWillMount` you dispatch an action like: `dispatch(fetchDataFromApi))` If the response code is 404, then in the action `fetchDataFromApi` you can dispatch another action, that is just an object like this one:

```
{type:SET_NOT_FOUND_ERROR}
```

That action will be handled by the reducer `dataReducer`, and will return a new state with an object (consider Immutability) that will have a property error, which will be a string with the reason, or whatever you want.

Then, in `componentWillReceiveProps` method, you, can check if the nextProps have or not have an error. If Error, you can render your error component, or even dispatch an action to go to the error page handled by react-router.

If no error, then you can dispatch an action (thanks to redux-simple-router) to go to the path y

Comment: The problem was not to do with the redux state. It is to do with how to change the redux-router status from a 200 code to a 404 code from the inside of a container or component. EG, when the redux state reports that it should.